# How to include "System.io" library without using Imports

Tags: vb.net, io, pipe

### My client workstation confirmed installed with framework 4.0 before accessing this program, but it return as below error. Can someone enlightended how to fix this problems.

see the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)
at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect()
at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  C:\Client_Pipe(New)\Client_Pipe(New)\client(new).vb:line 9
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
```

### at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam,  IntPtr lparam)

My code is as below:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim clientpipe As System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    clientpipe = New System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream("192.168.1.1", "soohhead", Pipes.PipeDirection.InOut, Pipes.PipeOptions.None)
    clientpipe.Connect()

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim len As String, recLen As String = 0
    Dim testString() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256").GetBytes(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    Dim recBytes(1000) As Byte, rec

    len = testString.Length

    clientpipe.WriteByte(len)

    ReDim Preserve testString(0 To len)

    clientpipe.Write(testString, 0, len)

    recLen = clientpipe.ReadByte()

    ReDim Preserve recBytes(0 To recLen)

    clientpipe.Read(recBytes, 0, recLen)

    rec = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recBytes)

    rec = Mid(rec, 1, recLen)
    MsgBox("check received line Number :" & rec & " at Length: " & recLen)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button2.Click

    clientpipe.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

I can't execute this program through client computers, but it only throw out exceptional handled message in error. Thanks to appopriate for any helps.

Comment: To me it looks like the stream is denied access to the ip address you're using.  It doesn't appear to be a library problem

Comment: hi tinstaafl, you are correct. I'd setup a namepiped server on domain server, the client workstation with low permission will not allowed pass through to it.

Comment: You probably need to get credentials that you can code into your program and pass them to the server.  You might have to check on any servers your request passes through, as well